# Template for Custom Post for the EDITOR

Tags: custom-post-types

I am attempting to make my custom post editor full page, like the Gutenberg editor. With no side menu or the meta boxes. I was thinking that in order to do that, I need to override the editor template somehow, but I have not find any way to do that.

According to https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/ there are ways to override single-{post-type}.php, archive-{post-type}.php and index.php. But none of those are used for the editor.

So, how can I modify the editor template (for my plugin only) AND/OR make my custom editor full page?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom CSS to the WordPress Admin by creating a new CSS file in your theme called admin.css (for example), and load it in the admin area by adding the following to your theme's functions.php file:

```
// Update CSS within in Admin 
function admin_style() {   
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/admin.css'); 
} 

`add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');`
```

(pulled from [this tutorial](https://davidwalsh.name/add-custom-css-wordpress-admin)).

I know it's not exactly what you're looking for, but you may be able to achieve what you want by hiding some elements and changing layout in CSS.